# RBAC or ACL, for private content?

Tags: php, django, content-management-system, security

Trying to build a micro-CMS (of sorts), which needs to dish out content i.e. images only, for the moment, to person logged in via a username/password.

Let's say there can be 10K such users, and each user has about 100-1K images in their own account, which *no one else* should be able to view. What would be the recommended approach to building such a system ?

My instincts tell me that ACL is the right approach, since the "roles" in my case are shared-nothing, so I'd have to create as many roles as users. Am I headed the right way ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A special kind of role could be an 'owner-role'. This role applies when you own an object. An idea for implementation in client code:

```
if ($owner->isAllowed('view', $image) { do stuff }
```

The RBAC system:

```
// initiation of roles somewhere
$this->roles->add(new OwnerRole($user); }

// when called
$roles = $this->getRoles($user);
foreach ($roles as $role) {
     if ($role->isAllowed($user, $action, $object)) { return true; }
}
```

This means the owner-role must be able to check who owns the object:

```
class OwnerRole implements Role
{
    public function __construct(OwernChecker $ownerChecker) {
        $this->owerChecker = $ownerChecker;
    }
    public function isAllowed(User $user, $action, $object) {
        if ($this->ownerChecker->userOwnsObject($user, $object)) etc
    }
}
```

The ownerChecker object can be given mappings of how to check a user owns an object.

The following are recommended reading:
http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/08/16/how-to-build-role-based-access-control-in-sql/
http://www.sqlrecipes.com/database_design/fine_grained_role_based_access_control_rbac_system-3/